# Porque existe esse "(jQuery)" no fim da function?

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber porque existe esta instrução `(jQuery)` no fim da `function`.

```
jQuery(function($){

    // alert('Oi');
    $(".widgets-holder-wrap").removeClass('closed');

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Talvez isto ajude. http://simplesideias.com.br/design-patterns-no-javascript-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você escreve `(function() { ... })()` você está tornando o código dentro da função literal (function literal), de forma que o objeto todo é na realidade uma função. Depois você está invocando a função, com os `()` no final. Isso é usado para controlar a visibilidade de funcões e variáveis. Os plugins do jQuery geralmente são escritos assim.

Sendo uma função, você pode passar o que quiser nos () no final. Por exemplo:

```
(function(jQ) { ... })(jQuery)
```

Essa é a definição de uma função que recebe um parâmetro jQ (conhecido somente no contexto da função) que em seguida está sendo chamada passando um parâmetro (que nesse caso é externo, uma referência ao jQuery).

Trabalhar dessa forma traz algumas vantagens:

- Você pode redefinir um parâmetro global e dar um nome significativo pra ele naquele contexto local.
- Há um pequeno ganho de performance já que é mais rápido procurar por algo no escopo local e não buscar na cadeia de escopos inteira até o global.
- Há beneficios ao comprimir o seu javascript.

Comment: Perfeitoooo !!! :)